# Search conditions across multiple tables

Tags: mysql

So I have the following tables:

- Searches: id, query
- Ingredients: id, name
- IngredientsRecipes: IngredientId, RecipeId
- Recipes: id, content, UserId, createdAt

What I would like to do is search for recipes with certain ingredients.

If my search query is "(cheese AND potato) OR pasta", that should return all the recipes that either contain pasta, or have both cheese and potato as ingredients.

How would I go about implementing something like this?

NB: That isn't how search queries actually look. I haven't decided how to tackle that yet.

I wasn't sure what to put as the title to this question; I welcome any suggestions of a more appropriate heading.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to attain here, when you say "go about implementing something like this" are you referring to just the query for the conditions that you mention, or to a program that translates a given input into a query?

Comment: @FranciscoPaulo I'm looking for an approach that lets me find recipes based on user inputted search terms. I'm having trouble finding an elegant solution for this because of the link table between ingredients and recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nothing more than your IngredientsRecipes table. It contains all relevant information.

e.g. To find a set of recipes given a set of ingredients:

```
select ir1.recipe_id from
IngredientsRecipes ir1 inner join
IngredientsRecipes ir2 on ir1.recipe_id = ir2.recipe_id
...
IngredientsRecipes irN on ir1.recipe_id = irN.recipe_id

where 
ir1.ingredient_id = 5 and
ir2.ingredient_id = 121 and
...
irN.ingredient_id = 80;
```

If you want to do multiple queries in one shot (because of ORs) then I recommend simply using a UNION between separate queries (because they really are separate queries after all).

Comment: Thanks. Doing inner joins on the link table with itself does the trick. :)